# solving a ODE with periodic boundary conditions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Help me please to solve this problem:
$u_{xx}+(\cos x+\cos^{2} x)u=e^{\cos x - 1}$

Thanks a lot!

Comment: 1. This looks like an ODE, not a PDE (there's only one independent variable). 2. What are the boundary conditions that you're referring to in the title?

Comment: Yes, thanks, it's ODE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The starting point could be changing the dependant variable:
$$\cos x=t$$
$$\frac{du}{dx}=\frac{d(\cos x)}{dx}\frac{du}{d(\cos x)}=-\sin x\frac{du}{d(\cos x)}$$
$$\begin{aligned}\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{du}{dx}\right) & =-\cos x\frac{du}{d(\cos x)}-\sin x\frac{d(\cos x)}{dx}\frac{d^{2}u}{d(\cos x)^{2}}=-\cos x\frac{du}{d(\cos x)}+\sin^{2}x\frac{d^{2}u}{d(\cos x)^{2}}\\
 & =-\cos x\frac{du}{d(\cos x)}+(1-\cos^{2}x)\frac{d^{2}u}{d(\cos x)^{2}}=-t\frac{du}{dt}+(1-t^{2})\frac{d^{2}u}{dt^{2}}
\end{aligned}$$
$$(1-t^{2})\frac{d^{2}u}{dt^{2}}-t\frac{du}{dt}+(t+t^{2})u=e^{t-1}$$
This is a second-order linear inhomogeneous equation with regular singular points at $t=\pm 1$. It does not look immediately familiar, so perhaps [Frobenius method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_method) could lead to a solution for the homogeneous part and [Green's function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_function) (as long as you state the boundary conditions) could be invoked for a particular solution.

**EDIT:**
The original equation without RHS is actually a [Hill equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_differential_equation)

Comment: Maple 16 comes up with the following general solution for the transformed equation:
$$u \left( t \right) ={{\rm e}^{t}}{\it HeunC} \left( 4,-1/2,-1/2,-2,3/8
,1/2+1/2\,t \right) {c_1}+{{\rm e}^{t}}{\it HeunC} \left( 4,1/2,-
1/2,-2,3/8,1/2+1/2\,t \right) \sqrt {2+2\,t}{c_2}+{{\rm e}^{t-1}}
$$
Note in particular that $u = e^{t-1}$ is a solution.

Comment: And thus $u = e^{\cos(x)-1}$ is a solution of the original differential equation.